# mysql/php - insert post serialized data to db with quotes signs, and retrieve it later without slashes - safety issue

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I am putting a serialized data to database. Data comes from input field and it can be anything (string), also with quotes signs. Serialized data I encode with base64 to preserve serialize to result error. But quotes marks became \'. I am aware that it is mysql injection remedy, and encoded data has crypted \' signs. Magic_quotes are on.
Here's the code:

$_POST['post']:

```
[0] => this is \"test\"
[1] => test2
[2] => quotes \"\"
```

php:

```
$db  = base64_encode(serialize($_POST['post']));
```

Now i get serialized and encoded data.
When I try to retrieve it:

```
[mysql functions to retrieve row]
$arr = unserialize(base64_decode($arr));
    foreach ( $arr as $arr1 ) {
    $arr2[] = stripslashes($arr1);
}
print_r($arr2);
```

After data retrieval I get as intended:

$arr2:

```
[0] => this is "test"
[1] => test2
[2] => quotes ""
```

Question is: is it mysql injection safe? Is it safe at all to put data from arr2 into html page into input fields and body of page? If not what would be a good method to do it? Should I use html_escape and mysql_special like functions ?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
string data from database will be used only as a value of input and textarea html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you've got magic quotes enabled. Magic quotes are deprecated.

Since you're using your own method to avoid injection issues, if you are unable to change the magic quotes setting for your installation, then stripslashes before you base64_encode the data - not when you decode it.

(I assume you are aware that the data structure you are creating is opaque to the DBMS thereby breaking normalization rules and making it impossible to query the data effectively).

> string data from database will be used only as a value of input and textarea html tags.

So you may (at a significant cost) have solved the sql injection problem but are not bothered about XSS attacks?

Use the provided functions for changing the representation of data *according to where you are sending the data* (i.e. mysql_real_escape_string, htmlentities etc).

Comment: I'm going to fight with XSS attacks via striping html tags via php functions. Hope it's enough. If you have better ideas I'm glad to hear them :)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$db  = base64_encode(serialize($_POST['post']));
```

to

```
$db  = mysql_real_escape_string(base64_encode(serialize($_POST['post'])));
```

And it will be injection-free.

Comment: Does it make any sense? post data is already encoded so it doesnt have any injections. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It's injection-free if you are sure it's always encoded because you can't promise that the post data is from your website.

If you are going to put $arr2 as html, you should use htmlentities since there are some quotes.

Comment: benck:
you're definately right, but whatever post data i put to database it's first base64 encoded so no matter what hacker would write it becomes encoded laaarge string. No $_POST data is written as query to db, only encoded POST data.
After all, retrieving data is stripped from slashes and put as html. Unfortunately if $post would be hacked in some way hacker can put to html any tekst. Maybe striping html tags would be the idea, but i'm not sure if it's really a trouble. More i am afraid of php injection and mysql injection than some new texts added. It wouldnt be a threat, rather a joke :)

Comment: I'm not sure why do you use base64_encode after serialize it? It takes more spaces.

Comment: yes i know but it's not an issue and gives me a lot of advantages. first of all if serialized data has some special signs like quotes, slashes or curled (i dont know correct word to describe) for this sign: {} it produces some errors - i read about it. so after conversion with base64 i lose any special signs because they are encoded. Secondly - because i have no quotes in it it should be mysql injection free. I guess size of encoded string it's small price for safety especially when input data is often very small (max 0,5 kb).